# When there stand two things, we call they stand “in parallel,” what do you call three or more things stand “in triangle”?

Tags: single-word-requests

We have a word, “並立 - heiritsu” meaning “to stand / line up in parallel” and “鼎立 - teiritsu” meaning “to stand on three foot facing each other” in Japanese.

For example we say “三者鼎立 – three parties coexist or stand against each other,” when we describe three big countries of England, France and Germany go their own way or stand against each other.

What is the English word to describe “presence of three or more parties on their own way” as an alternative to “in parallel” for two parties?

Let me clarify my point:

My question lies on the point – the phrase “並立‐in parallel” applies to **two straight lines** facing each other keeping the same distance on both ends, but the word “parallel” wouldn’t apply to the lines linking three points that forms an **equilateral triangle**, then how we should call the status of three points / lines combining each other in the state which we call “鼎立” both in Japanese and  Chinese using the same characters and different pronuciation (teiritsu in Japanese, dingli in Chinese), in English”?

There should be the concept and word equivalent to “鼎立” vis a vis “並立" in Engllish. What will it be?

Comment: I am thinking ***trilateral***.

Comment: Three things can stand in parallel.  You can have as many parallel lines as you can draw.  (Do you mean *confront*?)

Comment: I am not sure I properly understand this question. It is no fault of yours but probably due to the frequent incompatibility of English with Japanese, and the problem of finding equivalence of expression. As @Hot Licks points out it is perfectly possible for three, or any number of lines, all to be in parallel. The idea of a *tripod* is an entirely different concept to *in parallel*. I am also unclear about what you mean by *three parties stand against one another*. Do you mean *in opposition*, or *in support* of one another?

Comment: There's the ever-popular [Mexican standoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mexican_standoff).  Theoretically possible with only two parties, but most often seen with three or more.

Comment: WS-2. The problem comes from my ignorance of adoptability of the phrase ‘stand / exist ”in parallel”’ to more than two entities. I was under impression that the phrase, “in parallel” only applies to two things, drawn to the different Japanese wordings of “並立” used exclusively for two things and ”鼎立” exclusively for three things. Thinking over that three lines can go in parallel altogether, I come to realize three, four, five things can stand, exist, go, and run in parallel. Again it seems I was too adherent to “並立” ”鼎立.” So the word, “compatible” can be applied to more than two things as well?

Comment: Yes, there's more than one phone compatible with the Android operating system.  And, for the most part, the phones are compatible with each other.  It does get a little complicated, however, as to whether you're describing compatibility on a two-at-a-time basis among a number of similar objects, or describing simultaneous compatibility among multiple objects.  This can raise both technical and philosophical issues.  (But, on a human level, a group of people might be described as "compatible" if they all got along well together.)

Comment: This is a non-question. 1. "parallel" is not binary. 2. Being confrontational or opposing does not involve number. 3. what exactly is required is also unclear. Voting to close.

Comment: @YoichiOishi For the sake of clarity, in Japanese are "並立" and "鼎立" analogues in what they convey to a native speaker? I have the sense that the literal translations lose substantial nuisance. For example, does "並立" convey a state of unity or cooperation between two people, businesses, governments, etc; or, does "並立" simply convey existence without any sort of correlation?  Likewise for "鼎立"; additionally, does "鼎立" convey that there is some point of contention between the three involved parties?

Comment: @Corra. Both of Japanese words, 並立 (referring to only two) and 鼎立 (referring to only three) have a  nuance of facing each other, though they don’t always mean confrontation. It can be sometimes cooperative relationship. In the cold war time, the United State and Soviet Russia were in the relationship of ”並立.” In EU, England, France and Germany are in the relationship of “鼎立” as the countries vying for leadership in the region. So my question is whether I can say “A and B and C (and D, E, F) stand ‘in parallel’” as we can say “A and B stand ‘in parallel’ in terms of the balance of power.”

Comment: @Kris The reason it is 'unclear' is because the dear man is not a native speaker. In my opinion he is making a very sincere attempt to understand a Japanese linguistic term in English. What he doesn't need are boorish dismissals.

Comment: @YoichiOishi Sadly I do not understand *kanji*. But in the example you give, *parallel* does have resonance in the US - Soviet relationship, where it wouldn't, I believe, in the EU example you quote. But we are dealing here with a metaphorical use of *parallel*, and with metaphor, symmetry does not necessarily prevail in the way it might with geometry.. So although you could have three, or any number of parallel lines on a piece of paper - its metaphorical sense may not extend to three. But you have begun a very interesting conversation, and I would be glad to hear other opinions.

Comment: @YoichiOishi Thank you, I _think_ I have a better understanding now. Yes, you can use  "A and B" / "A, B, C and D" etc with your descriptor, it's actually parallel structure. Interestingly, I'm not sure there is necessarily a direct analog of the "in parallel" 並立 and 鼎立 convey because the structure itself is parallel and the relationship between them is whatever is needed.

Comment: @YoichiOishi Based on your example: During the Cold War, The United States and the Soviet Union were in opposition. During WWII, (Allies) The United States, the Soviet Union, France and Great Britain worked in tandem against (Axis) Germany, Japan and Italy. The Axis and Allies were cooperative within themselves and in conflict as entities. The collective members of the Axis and Allies weren't really "in parallel" individually.

Comment: @YoichiOishi Does the image of 並立 and 鼎立 always suggest equal heights? One can imagine two pillars that stand in the same direction (upright) but one is much taller - would 並立 be inappropriate in that context? If, as I suspect, it is inappropriate, then the relationship described might be that of *peers*. Peers can stand together in cooperation or stand apart in opposition, but are nevertheless understood to be "on the same level." It is often, but not always, implied that the peers in question stand above those who are not their peers.

Comment: @01d55. Neither 並立 nor 鼎立 refers to height, but more often than not refers to power. I think two Presidential candidates racing for Presidency on a 50:50 winning chance as 並立, and the power balance kept among three countries of  魏(wèi)、蜀(shǔ)、呉(wú)  in "Three Countries Warring Era" in ancient China (AD 220 -280) is a good example of 鼎立 status.

Comment: Ok, I'll throw this last one out before I go to bed. "Deadlock". The problem with this is that it only applies to opposing sides. Is there  a word that means, "At/On the same level" that works for  non contesting parties. Like saying "all of those guys are equally strong"

Comment: Are the three of them *in alignment* or are they *at odds*?

Comment: @Mazura. It's like international relationship. They are in alignment at a atime and at odds at another time. In case of 鼎立、two countries shake hands to alienate the rest. In both cases, each one claims its own presence and supremacy.

Comment: English idioms that represent countries as facing one another generally use combat terms without being specific about the number: "head-on", "toe to toe", "nose to nose". There does not seem to be a particular idiom for "two", "three", etc., parties. Other terms: "rivals". Depending on the particulars, "love triangle" or "eternal triangle" in which one is in a relationship with the other two, who are rivals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on clarification in the comments, I believe that 並立 and 鼎立 can be reasonably translated to an established English phrase: "To stand as equals."

This is a phrase that can be ascribed to rivals, colleagues, enemies etc. and can contrast with "standing above" or "standing below" in which height or vertical position is a metaphor for status.

For example, one might say that at the outset of the Democratic Primary, Hillary Clinton appeared to stand above Bernie Sanders, but he has since proven that he can stand as an equal with her.

Some meaning is lost in that 鼎立 seems to refer to two peers who stand above all others, but in context it is often implied that this is the case. And of course "standing as equals" does not specify a number, though it is most often referring few parties.

Answer (score 2):

After some more thought, I believe ***trilateral*** will work for your context of three (and ***multilateral*** for more than three).

> : involving three groups or countries
>   <sub>[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trilateral)</sub>

The analog for two parties would be ***bilateral***.

> When something is *bilateral* it has two sides or it affects both sides of something. Discussions between two political parties are called *bilateral* because both sides get to share their views.
>   <sub>[Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/bilateral)</sub>

Consider the following article describing an agreement signed by China, Japan, and South Korea (bold text is mine):

> On 13 May 2012, China, Japan and South Korea signed the Agreement among the Government of Japan, the Government of the Republic of Korea and the Government of the People’s Republic of China for the Promotion, Facilitation and Protection of Investment (“**Trilateral** Investment Agreement“).  The **Trilateral** Investment Agreement is the first legal framework between the three East Asian nations regarding investment and once in force, aims to enhance and protect investments made **trilaterally**, whilst also paving the way for a potential Free Trade Agreement between China, Japan and Korea. ...
>
> In addition to the more common protections that are covered under **bilateral** investment treaties already in force between China, Japan and South Korea (“Existing BITs“), such as fair and equitable treatment, most favoured nation treatment and protection against expropriation, the **Trilateral** Investment Agreement also promises improved government transparency, express protections for intellectual property rights and exceptions that will allow governments of the host State to take prudential measures to ensure the stability of their financial systems.  It also identifies international arbitration as the key dispute resolution mechanism for foreign investors.
>   <sub>[Herbert Smith Freehills](http://hsfnotes.com/arbitration/2012/06/26/trilateral-investment-agreement-signed-by-china-japan-and-south-korea/)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Edit: After reading the comment conversation I now think the first shot definition was way off.

Though, I believe even more now that "Tripartite" is a correct answer. It means three parties involved in the same thing. Parties here can be both individuals, groups, countries or any number of things. It can then be combined with several other words to fine tune the meaning, such as "Alliance" to mean three groups working on the same side or for the same ideal (in parallel/along the same lines). Further, it can also be combined with words like "Dispute" to mean three groups working against one another, that is, "contesting" (which could harken back to the three-cornered contest that I and others have seen).

For three people facing each other, I would say that it sounds almost metaphorical. Imagine three people standing in a triangle. In order for all of them to face each other they cannot be looking in the same direction as anyone else. This could mean "Because they are not looking in the same direction, they are not focusing on the same ideals and therefore working against one another." Which might mean the word's default is the "in contest" one, but can be altered with other Japanese words or phrases to mean "three working together" or "three in parallel."

Another thing I thought of is also a bit metaphorical, but changes the way I'm using parallel. Parallel lines never touch, by definition and so it would sometimes make sense that they aren't working together, but you can also look at them as trying to get to the same point. Racing to the same point and not working together can be seen as contesting against each other for the same thing. Parallel in this metaphor could mean what he's looking for, but not a standard way to look at the word in English.

But that's still a bit fuzzy. I'll link definitions later if this is still holding up. On my phone and it's tricky to do.

Comment: I'm not clear this is what the OP is getting at. At least his most recent comment and example do not suggest that. I have lived in Japan, though have no capability with the written language. Difficulties in translation are ever present. People sometimes say this is due to the different thought processes of Japanese v Western thinkers. I believe it has more to do with the fact that Japanese is an ideographic language (using pictograms), whilst English and European languages generally are alphabetic.

Comment: Sorry, hadn't woke, up yet. It's clear now, that the first part is wrong, from his comments. However, I still think the second part moght be close. He talks about both alliances and opposing forces using the same word. I believe that word he expresses isn't normally standalone and does mean "three people or groups" then with context, you can change it to mean working together (in parallel/with parallel ideals) or working against each other (in contest or contention). It would make a lot of sense that way. Of course, there also might not be an analogue in English...

Comment: He talks about the US and USSR having been *in parallel*. The only way that can be understood is as a metaphorical use of parallel. And idiomatically it has traction. But although parallel lines can be in any number, the metaphor doesn't seem to work when you start talking about multiple countries of the EU. Once you leave mathematics and enter the world of metaphor you are governed by idiom. And idiom is neither logical nor symmetrical. And my sense is that symmetry is what the OP is seeking.

Comment: Can you explain a little more about symmetry you mention? I don't have much experience in Japanese, so I might not have encountered this kind of symmetry before. Can you think of an English example of said symmetry?

Comment: I was the person who introduced "symmetry". It seemed as if the OP was seeking harmony between two things juxtaposed, and three things together - and that seemed to me to be a search for symmetry. But maybe I'm misinterpreting. I have tended to focus on his example in a comment of US-USSR and Britain, France and Germany in the EU. I don't think we are going to get any further with this unless and until the OP gives us some more input. In my experience an awful lot of translation issues between Japanese and English, end up as philosophical debates. Harmony is important to the Japanese mind.

Comment: @WS2 The people discussing "tripartite" are obfuscating the issue. Mr. Yoichi clearly mentions more than 3 parts (A,B,C,D,E, and F). Symmetry and Harmony are important concepts, but as the example describes partners who are not always acting in harmony, and often with changing political and economic strengths, I think "Balance" is closer to the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Two parallel lines never cross or intersect with each other **and**  the (minimum) distance between them remains the same to infinity.
 (Please note that I emphasize the “and” above solely to address the “binarity” of parallelism, for although “parallel” may not be binary in the sense that an infinite number of lines can be drawn that never intersect with each other, the constant equidistance part of the description of parallel lines can only be satisfied by a maximum of four parallel lines in a [three dimensional Cartesian coordinate system](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-place-more-than-four-distinct-points-in-a-three-dimensional-Cartesian-coordinate-system-such-that-all-points-of-interest-are-equidistant-from-each-other) and in the grand scheme of things, 4 seems closer to being binary than to being infinite.)
(link to a question on ‘Quora’ about the maximum number of points (and therefore parallel lines?) that can be equidistant from each other and one of its answers that says that the maximum is 4)

Contrary to parallel lines are the ones that eventually cross or intersect with each other and a tripod is formed when three non-parallel lines intersect/cross/come into contact at the same point, therefore I think  “in intersection” (in the sense of “coming into/having contact with”) would convey the opposite of “in parallel” in the literal sense, but in a figurative sense, I would equate “in parallel” to “[standing] **safely/comfortably apart**” and its opposite (in tripod) to “[standing] **dangerously close** or **too close for comfort**”

For the sake of world peace, two opposing forces (world powers, for example) are perhaps best kept “safely/comfortably apart” from each other, running/standing [in] parallel with the [equi]distance between them maintained by, among other things, the notion of “balance of power.”

(To the extent that “being/working in parallel” might [or even has to] imply to some that the two forces have the same interests and goal, one could argue that they both have the same interests, i.e., self interest/preservation and the same goal, i.e., peaceful coexistence.)

On the other hand, the relationship between entities (such as the EU powers mentioned in the question) whose paths purposely cross and intersect on a regular basis, although giving rise to great opportunities to resolve Europe’s problems and achieve its unity, also gives rise to more opportunities for head-on confrontations and such a close relationship could be characterized as one that’s “dangerously close” or “too close for comfort,” perhaps similar to the feeling some participants experience in a three-legged race, especially when a virtual stranger has been assigned to be their partner.

Answer (score 1):

The terms *vie*, *mexican stand-off* and *bilateral/trilateral/multilateral* have already been proposed or used in the original post.

You have also used the term "power balance", but I would like to suggest the more formal *balance of power* as an English term that captures some of what I understand of your descriptions of the Japanese terms.

> **Balance of power**
>   1 A situation in which states of the world have roughly equal power. *'As already noted, Soviet power was certainly an important element in the Cold War balance of power in East Asia.'*
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/balance-of-power)

(Note: there is a second way this term term is used: a small party that can tip the balance to one side or the other may be said to *hold* the balance of power, but this is not the sense I'm discussing in this post.)

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balance_of_power_%28international_relations%29) quotes Kegley & Wittkopf:

> The balance of power theory in international relations suggests that national security is enhanced when military capability is distributed so that no one state is strong enough to dominate all others.

Here is an example of the usage of the term:

> First, the general balance of power serves to prevent the system of states from being transformed by conquest into a universal empire ....
>   [- Bull (1977, pp.116-117) as quoted by Niou and Ordeshook in "The Balance of Power: Stability in International Systems (p.82) as Bull's summary of the meaning of balance of power](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=tUuj0V7Ma4wC&pg=PA292&lpg=PA292&dq=stand%20in%20a%20balance%20of%20power&source=bl&ots=wR43vCEY4e&sig=YIJs1SKBzTSY1aWCOAdFBbbDEbs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj67PPg0N3LAhUl6KYKHc2PCXEQ6AEIRzAG#v=onepage&q=balance%20of%20power&f=false)

The phrase includes the notion that the parties (states, in the context of international relations) to this balance are of equivalent power. For example, if the three Chinese states you [mentioned](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/315682/when-there-stand-two-things-we-call-they-stand-in-parallel-what-do-you-call#comment717032_315682) in comments were of equivalent strength, each of the three states would be an element of the balance of power in that context. The phrase also has something of *a nuance of facing each other, though they don’t always mean confrontation*, as [you put it](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/315682/when-there-stand-two-things-we-call-they-stand-in-parallel-what-do-you-call#comment716680_315682).

Answer (score 1):

Considering the tetrahedron analogous to OP's scenario, where the bottom face being the same unit as a "floor", such that the remaining three faces "lean against one another", and share a common vertex: the faces, or lines, can be considered as any abstract or concrete idea, such as presidential candidates, where the common vertex may be considered as the aggregate of their goals or some such thing. This is convergence or intersection, and is an idea from which, I believe, OP has completely diverged via basis of the axioms of tension and uncooperative competition.

We cannot consider three entities such as lines perpendicular to the vertices of a triangle to be "parallel" because [if imagined] they lack a common planar direction (comments on mathematically integrated idioms?). However, the noun "parallels" can still be used to refer to members of a tripartite committee.

If the fact that three people [or entities] are literally "facing one another" in a triangular formation is quintessential, then nouns such as "equivalence", "competition", or even "symmetry", might be used. Colourful and looser nouns such as "wits", or "blood" (They stand in blood) might also be used.