# Word-usage: Could the word “multiple stars” include binary stars?

Tags: word-usage

This question might be off-topic here, but concerning English usage.

We are translating some illustrated book for kids about astronomy, and then have a question as in the title.

Referring to Wikipedia etc., It appears that "binary stars" represents the star systems of two stars, whereas "multiple stars" does those of three or more stars.

Thus, our question is whether it is an abuse to use "multiple stars" for binary stars.

Simply, we don't know what to translate "multiple stars" into Japanese, because there is no one-to-one counterpart of words in Japanese.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not just say _binary and other multiple star systems_? Then you can use either one whenever you want.

Comment: @JohnLawler I'm sorry for insufficient explanation.  We are translating some book from English to Japanese and there is a definition of multiple stars --"Multiple stars are made of three or more stars 
that revolve in orbits around one another"-- in the English book. In Japanese, however, we do not have a specific word which represents the star systems of three or more stars only but do a word which stands for both binary and other multiple star systems altogether.

Thus, our question above arose.

Comment: @JohnLawler This sounds like a similar question with a similar difficulty from Mr. Yoichi. [https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/315682/when-there-stand-two-things-we-call-they-stand-in-parallel-what-do-you-call/315829#315829        ]

Comment: "Multiple-star systems are called triple, trinary or ternary if they contain three stars; quadruple or quaternary if they contain four stars; quintuple or quintenary with five stars; sextuple or sextenary with six stars; septuple or septenary with seven stars" (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_system). Do any of those have Japanese counterparts that will help you? I'm still unclear on the question.

Comment: Yes, a binary star system is a *multiple* star system. *Multiple* can mean "more than one" (for example, two).

Comment: @Silenus Thank you for your comment and sorry again for my unintelligible explanation.  Actually, Japanese has the counterparts of each star system of two or more stars and also has a general term which represents the star systems of two or more stars altogether. But, Japanese does not have the counterpart of "multiple stars", which is the general term and mean three or more stars.

Comment: English uses _uni_ , _bi_, and _multi_ for this type of numbering.It is like having an idiot child who counts "one, two, many". It comes from the Latin and it is possible that the the same concept does not exist in Japanese. Binary star systems are probably the most common in the galaxy, and in English that is what they are called. It would probably be best if you asked a Japanese Astronomer what they are called in Japanese :)

Comment: @Gandalf Then, as a consequences, in your opinion, we can not use "multiple star systems" for the star systems of two stars, right?

Comment: The problem is that you are asking if the English usage can be changed so that it translates into Japanese exactly. If what you have in Japanese is "_multiple star systems"_ for two or more, then that is what you will have to  use. But once again, it is best to ask a Japanese Astronomer what the _convention_ is.  See:  https://stardate.org/astro-guide/binary-and-multi-star-systems

Comment: @Gandalf >The problem is that you are asking if the English usage can be changed... Indeed, you're right. I got it. Thank you so much.

Comment: "Multiple stars" only means 3 or more in some narrow interpretations.  Eg, it may be the practice to imply 3 or more in certain technical contexts, but to the ordinary English speaker "multiple" means 2 or more.

Comment: @HotLicks >to the ordinary English speaker "multiple" means two or more.   That's very worth notice! Thank you!

Comment: Just don't ask us what "a few" means!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

All binary star systems are multiple star systems; not all multiple star systems are binary.